# Find solution of optimisation problem $\min_{x} \; x^TAx$ with constraint $\Vert x \Vert^2 \leq 1$

Tags: optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker, qcqp

I have to find the solution of the following problem : $A \in R^{n\times n}$ is a symetric positive define matrix
$$
\begin{cases}
\min_{x} & x^TAx \newline
s.c & \Vert x \Vert^2 \leq 1
\end{cases}
$$
With the lagrangian : $L(x, \sigma) = x^TAx + \sigma(\Vert x \Vert^2-1) $
I found the KKT conditions :
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
2Ax + 2\sigma x = 0 \newline
x^Tx - 1 \leq 0 \newline
\sigma (x^Tx-1) = 0 \newline
\sigma \geq 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$

But I don't know how to find $x^*$ that satisfies the problem.

Comment: Would $x=0$ not do it?

Comment: Are you sure it is not a maximum ?

Comment: Yes it's a minimum on my exercises sheet

Comment: Then @Julieawl9 answered your question.

Comment: If $A$ is positive definite then $x^TAx>0$ for all $x\neq 0$. In addition, $0^TA0=0$.

Comment: Yes it's one solution, but I was looking for another possible solutions, but thank you !

Comment: [+1] Interesting Problem.  Upvoted.

Comment: $0$ is the unique solution to this problem. Take any non zero $x$ then we have $x^TAx>0=0^TA0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is known that

$ \lambda_{Min}(A) \| x \|^2 \le x^T A x \le \lambda_{Max}(A) \| x \|^2 $

Equality in the left inequality occurs when $x$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the minimum eigenvalue of $A$, and equality in the right inequality occurs when $x$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the maximum eigenvalue of $A$.

In addition to the above, we have $ \| x \|^2 \le 1 $

Hence,

$ x^T A x \ge \lambda_{Min}(A) \| x \|^2  $

Now we have two cases:

1. If $\lambda_{Min}(A) \ge 0 $ then the minimum of $ x^T A x $ is $0$ at $x = 0$.
2. If $\lambda_{Min}(A) \lt 0 $ then the minimum of $x^T A x $ is $ \lambda_{Min}(A)$ , and this minimum occurs with $x$ being the unit eigenvector corresponding to the minimum eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: Ok thank you so much !

Comment: The eigenvalues of a positive definite matrix are always positive.

Comment: @Julieawl9  You're right, I didn't read the question well.